# MsAccess - How to make an ID field fill in other fields in the form?

Tags: database, forms, ms-access, autofill, auto-populate

**Problem:**

I'm trying to make it so when a numerical field is filled in with a certain ID it fills in the other fields accordingly to what the first field was filled with. So if a person were to type in their ID it would populate it with their name accordingly.

---

**Example:**

[image: Field 1]

But upon ID/numerical change I want it to do something like this:

[image: Field 2]

---

**Prior knowledge that may or may not help:**

-I know this is possible with combo boxes but having a combo box with 2k-8k entries seems absurd

-I don't really think subform is optimal for this situation

-I think you can do this with "=DLookup" but I don't exactly understand how to pull it off

---

Please and thanks for any help. All is appreciated greatly!

Comment: Are you okay using VBA behind the form?

Answer (score 0):

Some built-in Access mechanisms:

- Search field in the Navigation bar of the form.
- Find feature (Ctrl-F).

Alternatively, with VBA you can use your own UI design and have more control:

Obtain the desired ID from the UI in whatever way you like - a textbox, a button and a popup, etc. Don't use a textbox that is bound to the actual ID field (ID fields should be read-only and you shouldn't use an edit field for a search field - keep them separate).

In VBA, obtain the ID that user searched for and then jump to that record using code like this:

```
Me.RecordsetClone.FindFirst "StudentID = " & studentID
If Not Me.RecordsetClone.NoMatch Then
    Me.Bookmark = Me.RecordsetClone.Bookmark
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need VBA for this. Simply add the Student ID textbox value as a parameter the form's query and let it filter the results according the ID provided.

The query should be something like this:

```
PARAMETERS [Forms]![YourMainForm]![YourIdTextBoxName] Long;
SELECT *
FROM YourTableName
WHERE ((([Student ID])=[Forms]![YourMainForm]![YourIdTextBoxName]));
```

When you add a new ID, requery the form to see the results.

```
Me.Requery
```

Comment: So if I understand correctly I need to do this to each of the fields of First Name/Middle Initial/Last name?